# Web services con php para firebase

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs-2.0, firebase

hola a todos y gracias de antemano, queria cosultar, el modo de trabajar con un web sevices en php para colsultar datos en firebase, ya que al trabajar con angular2 los datos que almaceno se comprometen al dejar la conexion en enviroment, mi intencion es evitar eso. Mil gracias y perdon si la pregunta es muy tonta. busco en internet y no encuentro nada concreto.

Answer (score 2):

Si tu preocupación es la exposición de los datos de conexión de Firebase puedes quedarte tranquilo que eso de ninguna manera eso habilita a un atacante a acceder a tu datos siempre y cuando tengas las [reglas de acceso a tu BD](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) configuradas.

Si todavía estas interesado en acceder a Firebase desde el lado del servidor el [SDK Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) (librería nativas para acceder a Firebase desde servidor) esta disponible para Java, Node y python en este momento. Pero todavía puedes usar el acceso vía el [API REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) , de hecho hay librerias de terceros implementadas en PHP [aquí](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) y [aquí](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php).

Comment: La duda venia porque si bien estoy comenzando con Angular2 y demás tecnologías web, al compilar mi proyecto, los datos de conexión estan en main.bundle.js, cuando se compila en producción se renombra agregándole un hash, pero el archivo sigue estando ahí, y la idea es evitar visualizar claramente estos datos de conexión(por eso php y web services), pero consultando en otros lados me recomendaron lo mismo, configurar reglas de acceso a la BD, igual estoy  viendo los enlaces que sugieres. Toda información es importante, y mi intención es no dejar de lado la seguridad, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado si te sirvio la respuesta por favor marca la pregunta como respondida asi ya otros la pueden usar.